# Android Spinner click on already selected item

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin.Droid and MvvmCross.

In my view I have a spinner (MvxSpinner). When the user selects an item (in the spinner), an action should be performed. 
When the user 'selects' the same item again (the item is already the selected item), the action should be executed again.
Problem: Couldn't find a good way to intercept this 're-selection' of an already selected item.

Answer (score 0):

No fast way. Set an integer like lastItemSelected or lastIndexSelect where you put the value or index selected so when you click again the last item you can do what you want